# Is there a way to improve the queries in a loop on one in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Need to count the number of rows in which some attribute value ​​equal 1, 2, 3 and >3 in the best case.
Example:

```
for i in xrange(1,4):
    count = some_queryset\
        .filter(related__value__exact=i)\
        .annotate(count=Count('mtopening'))\
        .values_list('count',flat=True)
```

Is there a way to improve in an object-oriented way without raw_sql or with simple .extra select?

Comment: UPD. Need 3 different counts for this cases (1,2,3). So "_in" is not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Django's count method**

```
count = some_queryset \
    .filter( Q(related__value__gte=1) & Q(related__value__lt=4) ).count()  # This should work also without using Q()
```

**EDIT**

I don't think there is a direct way to do this in django, but I think the below code will do the job:

```
sums = []

for i in range(1,4):

    sums.append(
        QUERYSET.filter( related__value = i ).count() 
    )

print sums # will show you a list of sums of the values you want
```

Comment: i know about it, but i need count of objects with value=1, count2 with value=2 and count with value 3, not together in one count.

Comment: @ДмитрийКорнеев, Kindly find the `EDIT` in my answer